# Full height for a div

Tags: html, css, height

I can't figure out how a div can take the whole height of a container.
In the following exampe I'd like the "photo" div to take the full height, so that the yellow and green content are on the right of the photo.
Here is the code:

```
#header {
  background-color:#7b88d2;
  text-align:center;
  height: 20px;
}
#container {
  max-width:800px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#photo  {
  float:left;
  background-color:#FF3366;
  padding: 10px;
}
#logo  {
  float:right;
  background-color:#FF3366;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
#footer {
  background-color:#669933;
  text-align:center;
  height: 20px;
}
#col1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#col2 {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#txt_container {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color:#ffffcc;
}
#col3 {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

I can't declare the height in pixels because the height of the photo in unknow.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/wsfnqvyn/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's senseless. An image can be smaller or higher than your div (I don't know if it is relevant or not to what you are trying to explain). Try to use css background method instead.

e.g. Define the properties of your .photo class and then insert the code below to your html.

```
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url(image.jpg)"></div>
```

In this case, your .photo class should include this one line at least.

```
.photo {
background-size: cover;
}
```

Remember this method can restrict some CSS interactivity in rare cases.

Comment: Hi,Thanks but for some reason it reduces the size of the picture to the padding value of #photo: https://jsfiddle.net/wsfnqvyn/5/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle : See the updated one: https://jsfiddle.net/wsfnqvyn/6/

I use display:table and table-cell to achieve this.

```
#header {
   background-color:#7b88d2;
   text-align:center;
   height: 20px;
}
#container {
   max-width:800px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
}
#main {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display:table
}
#photo  {
   display:table-cell;
   background-color:#FF3366;
   padding: 10px;
}
#logo  {
   display:table-cell;
   background-color:#FF3366;
   padding-right: 10px;

}
#footer {
   background-color:#669933;
   text-align:center;
   height: 20px;
}
#col1 {
   float: left;
   padding-left: 10px;

}
#col2 {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#txt_container {
  display:table-cell;
   padding-left: 10px;
   background-color:#ffffcc;
}
#col3 {
   display: inline;
   float: right;
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```